# ftp_put always returning FALSE

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I'm generating a .csv file from a mysql query and the file is correctly saved on the local server where the creating query is. The next step would be to take that new file and upload it to a different FTP location (completely different server). I've tried almost everything, but I still can't get the ftp_put to work.

Here is the part of my code in question:

```
//Creating the file
$file = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . "/local_export.csv","w");

$csv_line = array("item1","item2");

fputcsv($file,$csv_line);

fclose($file);

$ftp_server = "00.000.000.00";
$ftp_user_name = "myusername";
$ftp_user_pass = "mypassword";

$file = dirname(__FILE__) . "/local_export.csv";
$remote_file = "remote_export.csv";

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// login with username and password

if (ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass)) {
echo "Connected as $ftp_user_name@$ftp_server\n";
} else {
echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user_name\n";
}

echo "Current directory: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";

// change the current directory
if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, "transfer")) {
echo "Current directory is now: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";
} else { 
echo "Couldn't change directory\n";
}

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY)) {
echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

In terms of the location of the two files, the local file is in:

```
http://subdomain.domain/folder/local_export.csv
```

While the remote file is going to go on the root / folder of the server (which is also the only one I have access to).

To me it looks like everything is in order, but still the code only generates the local file, always failing to save it to the remote location. I'm fairly new to moving files around, so I'm sorry in advance if the solution is in front of my eyes but I can't see it!

Many thanks in advance for your help.

***EDIT:*** as pointed out in the comments below, I should've checked if the connection to the server is successful or not. I've done those checks. The connection return successful (I've also tried independently via Filezilla to make sure the account I was given is able to upload in that location and it is.). So I guess I'm back at square one.

Comment: What about verifying the return values of function calls?

Comment: Hi @hek2mgl can you please be a bit more specific? How should I do what you suggest?

Comment: You need to verify the return values of your function calls. Especially `ftp_connect()` and `ftp_login()`. Isn't this obvious?

Comment: thanks for the reminder. I've edited the original question to reflect the fact that all those checks return a successful connection, still the file is not uploaded.

Comment: I'm still missing something like `if($conn_id === false) { die("connection failed");}` and `if($login_result === false) { die("login failed");}`

Comment: fixed now with the checks on the code

Comment: Try using `ftp_pasv` to make the connection a passive one.

Comment: hi, I've tried with `ftp_pasv` but it still doesn't work

Comment: Also try `ftp_put` in `FTP_BINARY` mode... And carefully check that, do you have write permission on default(root) folder? If not then use `ftp_chdir` to change to desire folder **OR** in FileZilla change the permission on default folder.

Comment: I've changed my code to BINARY and I've included the `ftp_chdir`, but still the file is not uploaded.

Comment: Hi @RyanVincent I'm using the relative path. Should I switch to the full URL?

Comment: Hi @RyanVincent thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the file still won't upload. I can see the full file dir now, but the result is not changing. (So frustrating, but thanks all for the support so far!)

Comment: check what is the result of function `ftp_chdir`

Comment: Hi @SzymonRoziewski I've added the check on `ftp_chdir` and once again it was successful: `Current directory: /` and after the change `Current directory is now: /transfer`

Comment: Ok, then another possibly reason could be the write permissions to this directory. First you can check the permissions by `fileperms` and if needed you can change them by `chmod`

Comment: @SzymonRoziewski all the permissions are set to 777 so I should be able to read and write without issues.

RyanVincent I'm not familiar with the command line, so I would not be able to implement your first solution.

Comment: You may do an exercise, try getting a file from a server `ftp_get`. If there is a file.

Comment: @SzymonRoziewski I've tried to use ftp_get to download a file that I had previously uploaded with Filezilla and I'm getting an error that will prevent the file from being downloaded.

I am now running out of options for things to check. I've also checked with the hosting company and they told me the ftp via php is not blocked in anyway (just in case).

As anybody any clue on how to proceed next?

Thanks in advance for the help, you are all great!

Comment: Try using another function for it `ftp_fput`. It may help.

Comment: Also please turn on error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: @SzymonRoziewski turns out there's something blocked on the server. The code above works perfectly on a different server, with the file being correctly created and uploaded. Is it possible that my hosting company is blocking the `ftp_put` function?

Comment: Yes, it's possible [link](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)